# "Reverse rebase" or "Rebase onto this" in git

Tags: git

Right now one of my more commonly used workflows is along the lines of:

```
git checkout branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git reset --hard branch
```

In other words, I want to rebase a branch onto this one and set this to the new rebase. Is there a builtin for this or do you have to start making aliases and stuff?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to rebase branch A onto master and then reset master to be the equivalent of branch A?

Comment: Start by explaining what you want done in text, not with git commands. You write "**along** the lines of", well, is it **along** the lines of (and thus not exactly like that) or is it **exactly** like that?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous exactly

Comment: Hmm... posted what I thought I recalled being the answer, but had a nagging doubt so retested... I don't have it quite right.  Will repost if I figure out what I did wrong...

Comment: Why are you running those commands? What is this workflow for? Is it how you merge a completed branch?

Comment: ^ Exactly. You can simple change the last command to `git merge branch` and pretty much achieve the same result. That's what merge is: 'reverse rebase'

Comment: Except then I get an ugly merge commit and an even uglier history

Comment: No, you don't get a merge commit if you've just rebased the branch. merge will just fast-forward.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're running those commands. Let's look at what those commands do. Let's say you have a branch.

```
A - B - C [master]
     \
      D - E [branch]
```

- git checkout branch
- git rebase master

```
A - B - C [master]
         \
          D1 - E1 [branch]
```

Ok, that's a normal way to use rebase to update a branch with master.

- git checkout master
- git reset --hard branch

```
A - B - C
         \
          D1 - E1 [branch] [master]
```

You wind up with the branch "merged" into master. This is one way to deal with merges. I presume you're doing this so you have a nice, linear history.

You can do that a little safer by replacing `git reset --hard branch` with `git merge branch`. This is safer because if master is a direct ancestor of branch then master will fast forward to branch and you'll have the equivalent effect.

But what if master *isn't* a direct ancestor of branch? `git merge branch` will merge and you still have a sensible history. But if you ran `git reset --hard branch` then master will be thrown away. For example, let's say, for some reason, you forgot the `git rebase master` or it failed, or you ran another command after it and it results in this.

```
A - B - C [master]
     \
      D - E [branch]
```

`git reset --hard branch` will quietly throw out master. This mistake is hard to detect.

```
A - B
     \
      D - E [branch] [master]
```

Whereas `git merge master` will perform a merge and master will still make sense.

```
A - B - C - F[master]
     \     /
      D - E [branch]
```

---

> *Except then I get an ugly merge commit and an even uglier history*

Not all merge commits are ugly. The ugly ones are "update" commits that are just housekeeping. That's what you avoid with `git checkout branch; git rebase master`. But when finally merging a feature branch you *want* a merge commit to retain the fact that a branch existed, what it was for, and what commits were in it. That context is important for understanding your code.

What I'd recommend you do instead is this:

- git checkout branch
- git rebase master
- ***Test that branch works***
- git checkout master
- ***git merge --no-ff branch***

Update branch as normal, resulting in this as before.

```
A - B - C
         \
          D1 - E1 [branch] [master]
```

But then it gets different. The first change, and why you shouldn't automate this whole process, is to verify that the branch works ***before*** merging it into master. This avoids breaking master. After the rebase, branch will be exactly the same as what will be merged into master, so testing branch then also verifies the merged master.

The second change is to use `git merge --no-ff` to force a merge, even though none is needed. The result is this.

```
A - B - C ------- F [master]
         \       /
          D1 - E1 [branch]
```

This is better because it *both* gives you a linear history (ie. `git log` will show the commits as F, E1, D1, C, B, A), and it retains that D1 and E1 were done together as a branch. This is important context for future people trying to puzzle out your code. Commits in a branch are often quite small and make more sense if they're understood in the context of a branch.

When you do it to the next branch, you still get a nice, linear history. The result is a series of near feature bubbles with no criss-crossing.

```
A - B - C ------- F ------- I [master]
         \       / \       /
          D1 - E1   G1 - H1 [branch2]
```

Finally, the merge commit offers a place to give more context about the branch. You can describe the purpose of the branch, or simply a link to an issue in your issue tracker.

Future code archeologists will thank you for it.

Comment: I know how to do a `--no-ff` merge, and I use it when it's appropriate. But the vast majority of the time I'm just working on a few small commits. If I were to make merge commits for all of them I'd need a 4k screen for `gitk` - hence the question.

Comment: @JV Again, this technique results in a linear history. Because each branch is first rebased onto master before merging, the branches don't overlap. This lets gitk display master and all the merged branches as two columns, one for master, and one for the branches. Each branch will result in a little bump. For an example, look at https://github.com/schwern/adventofcode2015

Comment: I know. That isn't the problem. The problem is that this workflow is the same as the snippet in my question with the `reset --hard` replaced by `merge --no-ff` - to quote the relevant part of the question: "Is there a builtin for this or do you have to start making aliases and stuff?"

Comment: @JV Yes, you'd have to start making aliases and stuff. I didn't bother with that because the workflow is based on the broken assumption that you can't have both merges *and* a neat history. And, as I said in the answer, you don't want to automate this because it will result in putting untested code into master.